# Why is my React component unmounting all the time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to render a text from a text input on an SVG. I run into the problem that the text is not rendered, since the font gets loaded then the element gets destroyed and the loaded font is empty again.

The text has to have an own font for every line so I put everything together into one object

```
const textObject = {
  font: false, //the opentype.js font object gets loaded into here
  fontFamily: false, // the font family gets set here
  fontSize: 100,
  text: "", //the actual text string to generate the path from
  color: "#000000"
}
```

App.js is setting up the DOM like this

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ContextProvider setLineNum={e => handleLineNum(e)}>
        {fontSelect}
        <TextBox />
        <TextOutput />
      </ContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
```

In context provider I have a function on the context that splits the text from the textbox into lines and assembles them into the textObject

```
  const editTheText = (t) => {
    const textLines = t.split(/\r?\n/);

    //remove last element of text array if empty
    if (textLines[textLines.length - 1].text === "" && textLines.length > 1) {
      textLines.splice(-1);
    };

    let textArray = [];
    textLines.forEach((line, i) => {
      textArray[i] = { ...textObject, text: line };
      setLines(i + 1);
    });
    setTheText(textArray);
    props.setLineNum(textArray.length);
    console.log("editTheText", textArray);
  }
```

The font object gets loaded into the text each time a new `<FontSelect>` is generated.

In FontSelect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (fontSelectRef.current) return; //run only once on mount
    fontSelectRef.current = true;
    setFont(initialFont, props.id); //Send Font name and line num (id of FontSelect component) to context
  });
```

In the ContextProvider:

```
  const setFont = (fontFamily, lineNum) => {
    console.log("setFont", fontFamily, "lineNum", lineNum, theText);
    if (theText[lineNum].fontFamily !== fontFamily) {
      console.log("New Font:", fontFamily);
      opentype.load('ttf/' + fontFamily + '.ttf', (err, font) => {
        if (err) {
          alert('Font could not be loaded: ' + err);
        } else {
          console.log("loaded Font:", fontFamily);
          setTheText(prev => {
            prev[lineNum].font = font;
            prev[lineNum].fontFamily = fontFamily;
            return [...prev];
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

This useEffect runs showing filled font, gets destroyed, runs again

```
  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log('theText effect is running', theText);
    return () => console.log('theText effect is destroying', theText);
  }, [theText]);
```

Now when I enter a text into the textbox, "editTheText" runs, sets theText.text = "a" but font is false again.

[image]

Why is theText destroyed all the time? Why is it running again but without the loaded text?

Edit CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-ptolemy-ckfg62 (ttf url is not working, tried several, doesn't work. It works however when I load them locally as you can see on the screenshot)

Comment: everything seems to be right, could you please make codesandbox for it ?

Comment: uh never did that, needs some time. also the font is loaded from local hard drive need to find the correct url so that it fits

Comment: In FontSelect your useEffect is getting run on every render, not only on mount

Comment: Also in the code sandbox the font never initially gets set

Comment: Yes because the ttf url is wrong I don't know how to get a working ttf url I tried google fonts but they produce wrong opentype error. The other ttf i have there now is not loaded either.
Why is the useEffect in FontSelect run on every render. Thought setting the useRef would prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few problems, the first is inside the ContextProvider and the second is inside the `FontSelect` function.

The problem with the `ContextProvider`:

```
  const textObject = {
    font: false,
    fontFamily: false,
    fontSize: 100,
    text: "",
    color: "#000000"
  };
  const [theText, setTheText] = useState([textObject]);
  const [lines, setLineNum] = useState(1);
  //const [fontList, setFontList] = useState({});

  const editTheText = (t) => {
    const textLines = t.split(/\r?\n/);

    //remove last element of text array if empty
    if (textLines[textLines.length - 1].text === "" && textLines.length > 1) {
      textLines.splice(-1);
    }

    let textArray = [];
    textLines.forEach((line, i) => {
      textArray[i] = { ...textObject, text: line }; // problem here
      setLines(i + 1);
    });
    setTheText(textArray);
    props.setLineNum(textArray.length);
    console.log("editTheText", textArray);
  };
```

The problem is that you are spreading the default textObject instead of the state from `theText`. The state in `theText` contains the selected font. So basically everytime a user types something, you are reseting `theText` state to it's default value.

Here is the proper function:

```
const editTheText = (t) => {
    const textLines = t.split(/\r?\n/);

    //remove last element of text array if empty
    if (textLines[textLines.length - 1].text === "" && textLines.length > 1) {
      textLines.splice(-1);
    }

    let textArray = [];
    textLines.forEach((line, i) => {
      textArray[i] = { ...theText[0], text: line }; // notice how we're spreading `theText` object
      setLines(i + 1);
    });
    setLineNum(textArray.length);
  };
```

The second problem is when you are setting the font inside `FontSelect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (fontSelectRef.current) return; //run only once on mount
  fontSelectRef.current = true;
  setFont(initialFont, props.id);
});
```

You have a useEffect that has no dependancy array which means that it will run on every render even when nothing has changed. You'll want to only set it when `props.id` changes which will only happen when it's initially rendered.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setFont(initialFont, props.id);
  }, [props.id]);
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it. Thought I initialize the new line with "...textObject" but in fact I reset it and then edited .text - somehow got confused there. With the useEffect however, that's why it's setting the ref.current to true so it drops out before running setFont again (got that from another Stackoverflow answer on how to run useEffect only once when I had a render loop with the props dependency.

Comment: PS: Still wondering why it is mounting and unmounting ("destroying") in ContextProvider useEffect. First output (not in the screenshot) is theText filled with font "AgbaMedium" and everything. Then it says new Font "AgbaMedium" then says it loaded the font, then it unmounts it again, mounts it another time (with font already loaded) then when typing a character, it unmounts and mounts again. Is this an effect of the opentype being async that it outputs textObject with font loaded but then says it loads the font?

Comment: Could you update the codepen? I'll take a look

Comment: If you want the useEffect to run only once on the initial render then you can pass it an empty dependency array `useEffect(() => {// Side Effect }, []); (notice [])`. What you did with the useRef is just a more complex way of doing it.

Comment: Just found out that the solution doesn't work... It works only replacing theText.text, but if another function changes another element of the text object, it gets overwritten with the value of the first entry in theText[0]. For instance if I change theText[1].fontFamily and then changing theText[someIndex].text, all the .fontFamily entries become that of theText[0].fontFamily.

Comment: the text state is currently ```const [theText, setTheText] = useState([textObject]);```, are you adding other text objects inside that array? If that's the case then you always have to access with [0] as there will be only 1 array. Also make sure you are not mutating the state directly and are instead doing it through `setTheText`